# Postgres server not listening

Tags: postgresql, remote-access, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect with my client (Macbook Pro) to a Postgres Database located in another PC in the same network (Ubuntu)
I can see the database from the host with pgAdmin, connecting to localhost, but I can't see from the client.

I've allowed all the connections in `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf`

I'm trying to connect from the client through pgAdmin to the IP server where the database is stored (192.168.1.34) and port 5432

[image]
And I get this error
[image]
What do I'm doing wrong?

Am I missing something

After reading suggestions, I can say:
On the ubuntu machine (home test server) I have no firewall.
Postgres is running.

I've tried from the ubuntu console to access to the database:
`psql -h 127.0.0.1 mydatabase postgres` and can connect (which means that the server is running and username is ok)
But if I try to access the same database, from the same machine, changing localhost with the IP, I can not connect.
Should not be `psql -h 127.0.0.1 mydatabase postgres` the same as `psql -h 192.168.1.34 mydatabase postgres` when I connect from the server?

Maybe is in loopback, as Alain suggested?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about your username and password?

Answer (score 16):

It's not connecting so it's likely not listening on the right interface or is blocked by the firewall.

Is postgres running?

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

Is postgres listening on tcp/5432 on your LAN IP or 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces)?

```
netstat -anpt | grep LISTEN
```

It could be listening on 127.0.0.1 (loopback) only which means it can't be reached from the Mac.

If it's not listening or is on loopback check postgresql.conf for listen_addresses:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Is there a firewall running on the Ubuntu box?

Make sure to allow inbound connections to tcp/5432 from the Mac's IP at minimum.

GUFW makes this easier to configure, but it can be done with iptables as well.

Further reference for the Ubuntu setup:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Comment: @ppardoz does this answer your question?  Please mark it correct if it does.

Comment: Interesting edit.  Postgres is definitely running and is allowing TCP connections on localhost.  That sounds like it is on loopback or pg_hba.conf isn't allowing postgres to log in from remote hosts.

Answer (score 15):

You have probably configured following two files

pg_hba.conf:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

You have to check if the port 5432 is open: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

If it's not then add a rule to your iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

0/0: If you want anybody to access it. 
You can change it to a specific ip address or range of ip addresses.

Answer (score 5):

You have allow postgresql to accept request from outside network. To do that you have to change two files located at `/etc/postgresql/{version_code}/main`
First one is `pg_hba.conf`, open and

change `host all all ::1/128 md5`  to  `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`

Second one is `postgresql.conf`, open and

change `listen_address = 'localhost'`  to  `listen_address = '*'`

Now restart the postgre server.

Comment: what if this has no effect?

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 17.04 default port is 5433 check file postgresql.conf in path /etc/postgresql/9.6/main

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, even thought had:

```
listen_address = '*'
```

when doing

```
netstat -anpt | grep LISTEN
```

there was nothing listening on port 5432.

The issue was in the  *pg_hba.conf** : I had configured the server to accept only local (socket) connection metching every host:

```
local   all      username       0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

changing **local** to **host** solved the issue

```
host   all      username       0.0.0.0/0               md5
```